# What is android:layout_alignParentEnd and how it differs from android:layout_alignParentStart?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, alignment, android-view

I got confused by `android:layout_alignParentEnd` documentation definition, as it says [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentEnd)

> If true, makes the end edge of this view match the end edge of the parent. Accommodates end margin.

What exactly is the "end edge of parent" and how we determine the difference between start edge of a view and end edge of a view?

And also the same thing is confusing me in `android:layout_alignEnd` and `android:layout_alignStart`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What exactly is the "end edge of parent"

The parent in this case is the `RelativeLayout`. For most languages, `end` is on the right. For RTL languages (e.g., Arabic, Hebrew), `end` is on the left.

> how we determine the difference between start edge of a view and end edge of a view?

For most languages, `start` is on the left and `end` is on the right. For RTL languages, `end` is on the left and `start` is on the right. Note that the RTL support assumes that you are running on API Level 17+ and [have `android:supportsRtl` set to `true`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl).